# Blazor: Reduce/Elimination of animation speed of a chart

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

is it possible to reduce or even turn off the animation speed at the usage of the ChartJs.Blazor's BarChart component in Blazor? I have found this NuGet package to be very useful, but I don't see how would it be possible to turn off the animation whenever I update my BarChart. For the easier overlook, here is a simplified version that I am testing on now:

```
@using ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.BarChart
@using ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.BarChart.Axes
@using ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Axes
@using ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Axes.Ticks
@using ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Properties
@using ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Wrappers
@using ChartJs.Blazor.Charts
@using ChartJs.Blazor.Util
@using BootstrapChart1.Data
<h2>Simple Bar Chart</h2>
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddData">
        Add Data
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="RemoveData">
        Remove Data
    </button>
</div>
<ChartJsBarChart @ref="_barChart"
                 Config="@_barChartConfig"
                 Width="600"
                 Height="300" />

@code {
    private BarConfig _barChartConfig;
    private ChartJsBarChart _barChart;
    private BarDataset<DoubleWrapper> _barDataSet;

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        _barChartConfig = new BarConfig {
            Options = new BarOptions {

                Title = new OptionsTitle {
                    Display = true,
                    Text = "Simple Bar Chart"
                },

                Scales = new BarScales {
                    XAxes = new List<CartesianAxis> {
                        new BarCategoryAxis {
                            BarPercentage = 0.5,
                            BarThickness = BarThickness.Flex
                        }
                    },
                    YAxes = new List<CartesianAxis> {
                        new BarLinearCartesianAxis {
                            Ticks = new LinearCartesianTicks {
                                BeginAtZero = true
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },
            ResponsiveAnimationDuration = 0,

            }
        };

        _barChartConfig.Data.Labels.AddRange(new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"});

        _barDataSet = new BarDataset<DoubleWrapper> {
            Label = "My double dataset",
            BackgroundColor = new[] {ColorUtil.RandomColorString(), ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
            ColorUtil.RandomColorString(), ColorUtil.RandomColorString()},
            BorderWidth = 0,
            HoverBackgroundColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
            HoverBorderColor = ColorUtil.RandomColorString(),
            HoverBorderWidth = 1,
            BorderColor = "#ffffff"
        };

        _barDataSet.AddRange(new double[] {8, 5, 3, 7}.Wrap());
        _barChartConfig.Data.Datasets.Add(_barDataSet);
    }


    private void AddData() {
        var nowSecond = DateTime.Now.Second;
        _barChartConfig.Data.Labels.Add(nowSecond.ToString());
        _barDataSet.Add(new DoubleWrapper(nowSecond));

        _barChart.Update();
    }
}
```

Source of the extension: https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of the co-authors of the ChartJs.Blazor library.

In order to disable the animations, you have to set the animation duration to 0 wherever possible. This is documented in the chart.js-docs [performance-section](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/performance.html#disable-animations).

You can already set the `BarOptions.ResponsiveAnimationDuration` and the `BarOptions.Hover.AnimationDuration` to `0` but currently we're missing the `BarOptions.Animation` option. There is a pull request open but not merged/released yet.

I will fix this before the next nuget-release. If you need it right now, you can subclass the `BarOptions` class and add the `Animation` property (of type `Animation`) yourself. Then use your subclass instead of the original `BarOptions` and you can set `YourBarOptions.Animation.Duration` to `0` as well.
If you don't manage to do that, write a comment; I can included the code you need but please try it yourself first :)

### Update

I have fixed it and released a new version. [Release-1.1.0](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor/releases/tag/v1.1.0) is published and available [on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChartJs.Blazor/).

Comment: I managed to do it, it works beautifully in my bigger system. Thank you!!!

Comment: Awesome! Make sure to accept this answer so your question gets marked as answered. Also consider upvoting :)

Comment: @Zolly I have edited the answer to provide a link to the new version. It's fixed, you can check it out on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChartJs.Blazor/). You should also consider accepting this answer so your question is marked as solved. You can do that by checking the checkmark on the left of the answer. Thank you :)